# Google Remote API 404 on Springboot

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-boot, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm trying to connect a Spring Boot app running locally/not in Google app engine when deployed to my Google DataStore. I am using Objectify and Google Remote API as my understanding is that Objectify will only work if deployed in App engine(?). The problem is that the Google Remote API is throwing 404 when I try and communicate with the DataStore. I think I might have my config wrong in spring boot as the instructions on the [google docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/remoteapi) talk about setting up config in web.xml which I don't use on my JAR based spring boot app. I have created a SpringBootServletInitializer class to try and register the servlet (code at the bottom). I'm coming at this from an AWS perspective and so far I've found Google cloud to be a nightmare! Connecting to DynamoDB is so much simpler and I feel I must be missing something!

```
import com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Thomas on 01/07/2017.
 */
@Configuration
public class GoogleRemoteApiConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(GoogleRemoteApiConfig.class, "/remote_api");
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean remoteApiRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new RemoteApiServlet(), "/remote_api");
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        registration.setInitParameters(params);
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.setUrlMappings(Arrays.asList("/remote_api"));
        registration.setName("RemoteApiServlet");
        return registration;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using GAE flexible. You might want to check https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#can-i-use-objectify-from-a-gae-flexible-runtime. Have you tried https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Setup#guice-alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd fundamentally misunderstood how the remote-api worked, and didn't realise I needed an app running in app engine to proxy the requests on to Google DataStore. I'm still confused that there is no simple way to access DataStore from Java but this approach is at least working!